# How to store parse_url as a string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, parse-url

I have the following code:

```
$array = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$Ur = $array['host'];
```

which displays the domain just fine, but when I use this with sessions, it doesn't work. Also, I tested it with **gettype** and it returns **Null**? I thought it was an array?

Anywho, how do I go about converting the above $Ur into a string?

Cheers!

Comment: How are you "using" it with sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

provide a second component parameter = PHP_URL_HOST to [parse_url](https://www.php.net/parse_url) and it will return a string instead of an array

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you **store or access** the sessions, you have to call [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/session_start) before you do or you won't see or be able to access the results later.

If you just want the referrer URL as a string, why not:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

?

Comment: Hi, because I just need the domain value. - Session_start is being called